# removing dye from wood floor

Tags: wood, staining

I'm not sure if this falls within the scope of this site.

Is it possible to remove a stain made from the dye of a couch's fabric from a wood floor?

I have looked online and found different methods, but I am not sure which is the best way.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the stain is on the surface of the floor finish and has not penetrated.  The stain does not look like it dripped on the floor. It would help to know how the stain was applied or got on the flooring?

Comment: I believe it was from a blue couch that was there

Comment: Are you certain this is from a dye or is it from foot traffic in front of the couch?  Have you tried solvents and/or cleaning fluids

Comment: I was told there was a blue couch there and they didnt see this stain before it was removed

Comment: *"I have looked online and found different methods, but I am not sure which is the best way.*" Please list the different methods you've read about, the more complete the Question the better the Answers can be.

Answer (score 1):

It does not make a lot of sense that the dye in the couch came off, although it is possible that some dye was released during a steam cleaning.  But if that is the case, the discoloration would extend around the couch and not just be at the front edge of the seat. Before anything else try using stronger detergents on the flooring with some steel wool abrasive to insure that the discoloration is not above the floor varnish.  Of that does not work you will have to sand down the surface finish.  It may be possible to only remove the top of the finish surface and then apply a fresh coat of varnish (or possibly polyurethane) in that area only, but it will require buffing to match up the area to the appearance of the adjacent areas.  If it is still visible, it may be necessary to recoat the entire floor.

Comment: makes sense to me.  ive seen it happen elsewhere.